# Show isomorphism of two different groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am fairly new to group operations and given with this problem. I did not manage to come up with anything meaningful - Hence, I am kindly asking for support. Thanks!

Let $(G, \cdot)$ and $(H, +)$ be groups, and $G$ be isomorphic to $H$.

**Show that $(G \times F^*_3, \circ)$ and $(H \times \text{sym}(2), \oplus)$ are isomorphic,**

where $\circ : (G \times F^*_3) \times (G \times F^*_3)$ , $(a_1, a_2) \circ (b_1, b_2) := (a_1 \cdot b_1, a_2 \cdot b_2)$,

represents the component-wise group operation on  $G$ and $F^*_3$,

and $\oplus : (H \times \text{sym}(2)) \times (H \times \text{sym}(2))$ , $(a_1, a_2) \oplus (b_1, b_2) := (a_1 + b_1, a_2 \circ b_2)$,

represents the component-wise group operation on $H$ and $\text{sym}(2)$

Comment: $sym(2)$ and $\Bbb F_3^{\times}$ both have two elements, so they are isomorphic. Since $G\cong H$, we are done.

Comment: Could you please add a little more explanation, so I can understand, please?

Comment: @MikeM. First make sure you understand why $G \times X \cong H \times X$ for any group $X$. Then prove that $\mathbb{F}^\times_3 \cong \text{sym}(2)$ and use $G \times X \cong H \times X$ twice.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.